# Problem with crouching on my first person controller

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im kinda new to c# and to unity in total, so when i tried to add crouching to my controller script it got buggy, my camera shake when im trying to crouch and sometimes button doesn't work

also tried to watch some tutorials and look at some docs which didn't really help.
here's my code and components on my controller in inspector:

[image]

```
public bool CanMove { get; private set; } = true;
private bool IsSprinting => canSprint && Input.GetKey(sprintKey);
private bool ShouldJump => Input.GetKeyDown(jumpKey) && characterController.isGrounded;
private bool ShouldCrouch => Input.GetKey(crouchKey) && !duringCrouchAnimation && characterController.isGrounded;
private bool isCrouching;
private bool duringCrouchAnimation;


[Header("Functional options")]
[SerializeField] private bool canSprint = true;
[SerializeField] private bool canJump = true;
[SerializeField] private bool canCrouch = true;

[Header("Controls")]
[SerializeField] private KeyCode sprintKey = KeyCode.LeftShift;
[SerializeField] private KeyCode jumpKey = KeyCode.Space;
[SerializeField] private KeyCode crouchKey = KeyCode.LeftControl;

[Header("Movement Parameters")]
[SerializeField] private float sprintSpeed = 15.0f;
[SerializeField] private float walkSpeed = 10.0f;
[SerializeField] private float crouchSpeed = 5.0f;

[Header("Look Parameters")]
[SerializeField, Range(0.1f, 5.0f)] private float sensitivityX = 2.0f;
[SerializeField, Range(0.1f, 5.0f)] private float sensitivityY = 2.0f;
[SerializeField, Range(1, 180)] private float upperLookLimit = 85.0f;
[SerializeField, Range(1, 180)] private float lowerLookLimit = 85.0f;

[Header("Jump Parameters")]
[SerializeField] private float JumpForce = 8.0f;
[SerializeField] private float gravity = 30.0f;

[Header("Crouch Parameters")]
[SerializeField] private float crouchHeight = 0.5f;
[SerializeField] private float standingHeight = 2f;
[SerializeField] private float timeToCrouch = 0.25f;
[SerializeField] private Vector3 crouchingCenter = new Vector3(0, 0.5f, 0);
[SerializeField] private Vector3 standingCenter = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);


private Camera playerCamera;
private CharacterController characterController;

private Vector3 moveDirection;
private Vector2 currentInput;

private float rotationX = 0f;

void Awake()
{
    playerCamera = GetComponentInChildren<Camera>();
    characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    Cursor.visible = false;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

void Update()
{
    if (CanMove)
    {
        HandleMovementInput();
        HandleMouseLook();

        if (canJump)
            HandleJump();

        if (canCrouch)
            HandleCrouch();

        ApplyFinalMovements();
    }
}

private void HandleMovementInput()
{
    currentInput = new Vector2((isCrouching ? crouchSpeed : IsSprinting ? sprintSpeed : walkSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), (IsSprinting ? sprintSpeed : walkSpeed) * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));

    float moveDirectionY = moveDirection.y;
    moveDirection = (transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward) * currentInput.x) + (transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.right) * currentInput.y);
    moveDirection.y = moveDirectionY;
}

private void HandleMouseLook()
{
    rotationX -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivityY;
    rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, -upperLookLimit, lowerLookLimit);
    playerCamera.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, 0, 0);
    transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(0, Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivityX, 0);
}

private void HandleJump()
{
    if (ShouldJump)
        moveDirection.y = JumpForce;
}
private void HandleCrouch()
{
    if (ShouldCrouch)
        StartCoroutine(CrouchStand());
}
private void ApplyFinalMovements()
{
    if (!characterController.isGrounded)
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

    characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}

private IEnumerator CrouchStand()
{
    if (isCrouching && Physics.Raycast(playerCamera.transform.position, Vector3.up, 1f))
        yield break;

    duringCrouchAnimation = true;

    float timeElapsed = 0;
    float targetHeight = isCrouching ? standingHeight : crouchHeight;
    float currentHeight = characterController.height;
    Vector3 targetCenter = isCrouching ? standingCenter : crouchingCenter;
    Vector3 currentCenter = characterController.center;

    while(timeElapsed < timeToCrouch)
    {
        characterController.height = Mathf.Lerp(currentHeight, targetHeight, timeElapsed/timeToCrouch);
        characterController.center = Vector3.Lerp(currentCenter, targetCenter, timeElapsed/timeToCrouch);
        timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;

        characterController.height = targetHeight;
        characterController.center = targetCenter;

        isCrouching = !isCrouching;
        
        duringCrouchAnimation = false;
    }
}
```